# What is the name for building trust on a platform before pillaging?

Tags: social-engineering

What's the common or recognized name for a vulnerability on a platform where someone can build trust and than pillage/exploit that trust for profit or information? It's driving me crazy, and I constantly forget it every time I want to use it, and than I'll read it in a paper a few months latter.

Comment: do you mean "pre-texting"?

Comment: no. The name for something like building up trust on a marketplace like ebay with a bunch of small legitimate transactions and than make a large fraudulent transactions to profit until booted. Or if in a PoS blockchain if witnessing nodes have a reputation score but nothing staked, so it's more profitable to build your reputation, and that become a bad actor.  That's probably the last place i read it was in a PoS white paper, but can't remember which one. And the vulnerability or hack has a name.

Comment: I feel like [money.se] or [law.se] might know.

Comment: @WindDude I feel like that would almost fall under the name of Social Engineering since you're building yourself up as trustable before using that falsely placed trust for personal gain at the trusting party's expense.

Comment: @JesseP. Well the tag the question is under is [tag:social-engineering], so that makes me think that OP is looking for a name under the _subset_ of social engineering, not for that term itself.

Comment: @forest That's a fair assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sybil Attack

> the attacker subverts the reputation system of a peer-to-peer network
>   by creating a large number of pseudonymous identities, using them to
>   gain a disproportionately large influence. A reputation system's
>   vulnerability to a Sybil attack depends on how cheaply identities can
>   be generated, the degree to which the reputation system accepts inputs
>   from entities that do not have a chain of trust linking them to a
>   trusted entity, and whether the reputation system treats all entities
>   identically.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybil_attack

Answer (score 4):

**Subterfuge** is the act of using deceit in order to reach a goal.

You are being deceitful in nature when you legitimately build trust within an environment you plan on harming later.

Comment: That fits, but I don't think that was it.  Might have to skim a few white papers tonight because it is driving me crazy! And it's happened more than once.